# Template vs pure virtual function

Tags: c++

I have an `enum class Type`. If I have a base class and a derived class like this:

```
template<Type T>
class Templated
{
public:
    Type GetType() const
    {
        return T;
    }
};

class DerivedTemplated : public Templated<Type::None>
{
};
```

Is this better in any way than having this:

```
class NoTemplate
{
public:
    virtual Type GetType() const = 0;
};

class DerivedNoTemplate : public NoTemplate
{
public:
    Type GetType() const override { return Type::None; }
};
```

Using templates is not necessary in this case, but I don't know if I should use them or not. I often store polymorphic collections of the base class, so in the templated case I would have to create an interface:

```
class ITemplated
{
public:
    virtual Type GetType() const = 0;
};
```

and derive `Templated` from it. Are there any benefits to the templated one over the pure virtual function?

Comment: Polymorphism and templates are not the same thing. If you need to store multiple types of data in the same structure you need polymorphism.

Comment: It's not clear from this code what the problem you're trying to solve actually is, so it's hard to say if this is the right approach or not.

Comment: The approach of defining a virtual interface for a class template _is_ indeed an approach that can be (and is) used when appropriate. It boils down to what is most meaningful in your code. Remember, each value of `T` provided to the class template produces an entirely new class. So if that's what you want, then go for it. Don't forget that by using templates you will essentially restrict certain code to being header-only, which may increase compilation time in large projects or create other challenges if you want to hide code or methods behind an API.

Comment: Usually one would use either virtual functions or template but not both. And why do you need to have an enum case. Mixing multiple paradigms (for the same set of related classes)  can make the program harder to undestand.

Comment: @Phil1970 yes i think you are right, i will use virtual functions for this, i need to have an enum because sometimes i need to choose particular types from a collection and do something with them (the enum stores the type)

Comment: See also `typeid`

Comment: Unless you need to store derived classes object in a file or database and be able to recreate appropriate objects or something similar, it is otherwise preferable to avoid having an associated type and use virtual function for any behavior that depends on the type.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first makes no sense. Because how would you use this? For example

```
template<Type T>
int int_of_type(const Templated<T> &bar) {
    return hash(bar.get_type());
}
```

why not just write:

```
template<Type T>
int int_of_type(const Templated<T> &) {
    return hash(T);
}
```

or

```
template<Type T>
int int_of_type<T>() {
    return hash(T);
}
```

I see no way the `get_type` can be used where you couldn't just use `T` directly. Maybe you need a more complex example to show what you are trying to solve.

Comment: The problem is as I said (maybe I did not say it clearly enough), if I, for example, have a `std::vector` of the `ITemplated` interface, I wouldn't be able to access T, thats why I would use the `GetType()`

Comment: You mean `DerivedTemplated` since this was about the first example. And those would be `template<typename Derived>` from which I believe you can deduce T unless you have multiple inheritance.